# Adding fresh fruit to a non fruited banana bread

Tags: baking, chocolate, fruit, nuts, bananas

I have a banana bread recipe that I love.  I want to add other fresh fruit and nuts or chocolate to it.  Do I need to adjust the other ingredients to take into account these additions?

Answer (score 5):

If you add chocolate and nuts, no. They can be added without any adjustments, as they don't tend to affect the rest of the cake at all. Fresh fruit is a bit trickier, since it tends to release a great deal of liquid when cooked which can make the result soggy. In general, if you add fresh fruit to a cake you want to toss it in some starch (eg corn starch or potato starch) to absorb the liquid it will release. Each piece of fruit should be completely coated and then just folded into the batter.

Comment: Will the starch help the fruit to stay suspended in the bread as well as absorb the juices?

Comment: @Suzanne that's a myth.

Comment: RonJohn,I know it won't "absorb" the juices, it will thicken them.  Will it prevent the fruit from sinking?